# Expired jobs not showing up in favorites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I had bookmarked a few jobs in my favorites some time back. However, now it is not showing up my previously bookmarked jobs.

1. Is it like favorites only show the jobs which are currently active?
2. Is there any archive where I can find my previously bookmarked jobs description.
3. I have no clue how to get my previously saved jobs.
4. *If we do not have such feature, shall we vote to request for such feature?*

---

**Update:** A few days back I had bookmarked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/132074/c-sharp-developer-expert-c-sharp-typescript-bluestone) job. And without any notification, it disappeared today. However, on searching my browser's history I found the link.

Since the page exists clearly highlighting that - **"This job is no longer accepting applications."**

**So why it can't be still in my favorites?** Why my favorites are getting removed without any notification?

***As a solution, we can have just grayed out favorites.***

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to look at jobs which aren't available any more?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson |------|
Because I have less experience and most of the time I do not have the required skill sets for the jobs posted. However, the skill requirements gives me the clear picture as what is in demand in my area of technology stack. |------| 
And, so that I can prepare myself in the right direction to be eligible for such type of jobs in the near future. For me the posted jobs serves as a source of motivation to learn and grow. |------|
I hope, I justified that why I want to look at jobs which aren't available any more... :)

Comment: Seems like you should archive them locally with timestamps for your use-case?

Comment: Please consider that, if the job offer is expired, the company may prefer to remove all references to avoid confusion and late applications (by e-mail or other mean beyond SO).

Comment: @Zanon : I understand your point is valid. However, it is also very common to see the expired jobs in careers section of any company's website. And moreover archiving the jobs safely (after removing all channels for late application) is something which is attainable.

Comment: Isn't wrong the entire concept of "bookmark" if it expires? I mean, you either are not allowed to bookmark, or your bookmarks are supposed to stay there. If you bookmark a page in your book, the only way to lose the bookmark is to lose the entire book. We always gets very disappointed where our browser bookmarks don't exist anymore, so I would argue that at least from a user experience point, if you allow bookmarking you have to keep them within the system (even if hidden) or remove the whole bookmark feature, which sets certain expectations for the user.

Comment: You won't find expired jobs on any reasonable job board. HR people don't want to be bothered with old issues that simply waste their time

Comment: Seems reasonable to have a list of favorites where the inactive jobs are faded out, like a heavily downvoted answer. And the apply button should be disabled and make it clear that the job is no longer available.

Comment: I'm disappointed to see the lack of response to this, even I want this kind of feature.